# TypeError: Cliente.find is not a function en Sails

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ejs, sailsjs

Estoy intentando renderizar una vista y presenta el mensaje de error, creo que el problema va por la sintaxis, si me pueden ayudar he realizado varios cambios y ya estoy confundido. Si alguien me puede aclarar.

Primero versiones que estoy manejando para mi app:
PostgreSQL 14
sails --version
1.5.2
node --version
v12.22.9

Dependencias:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "async": "2.0.1",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.5",
    "postgresql": "0.0.1",
    "sails": "^1.0.2",
    "sails-hook-flash": "^0.2.2",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^3.0.2",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.0.0-16",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^1.4.0",
    "sails-postgresql": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sailshq/eslint": "^4.19.3"
  },
```

Adjunto la función de mi contolador, para este punto del problema:

```
  listaClientes: async (peticion, respuesta) => {

    let clientes = await Cliente.find()
    respuesta.view('pages/admin/lista-clientes', { clientes })

  },
```

Error que me presenta:

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 TypeError: Cliente.find is not a function
    at Object.listaClientes [as admin/listaclientes] (C:\Datos\Cursos\Sails\Tfotos\api\controllers\AdminController.js:88:34)
```

Si alguien me puede dar una mano, gracias. Estoy atento por si algún detalle adicional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa que /config/globals.js tenga  models: true,

Tambien Revisa que el nombre de Tu Archivo Modelo 'CLiente.js' este Correctamente Definido

Comment: Gracias, si lo revise y estaba según tu indicación. La verdad no se que mismo cambie y ya esta funcionando.